# ListView not navigating to other activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to get my list view to navigate to different activities based on a specific item that has been tapped. I know that the code is what's need but I don't know what I need to change my to

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class WC_line extends ListActivity {

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            items.add(new EntryItem("Bank", "Fare zone 1"));
            items.add(new EntryItem("Waterloo", "Fare zone 1"));

            EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


            @Override
            public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
                //When clicked, go to specific activity
                if (position == 0) {
                    //code specific to first list item
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity_1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            };
    }
```

[image: error screenshot]

XML
[image: XML file]

**@Override error**

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class WC_line extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView list = getListView();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wc_line);

        items.add(new EntryItem("Bank", "Fare zone 1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Waterloo", "Fare zone 1"));

        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
        //When clicked, go to specific activity
        if (position == 0) {
            //code specific to first list item
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WC_Bank.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

[image: override error]

[image: boolean error]

Comment: so what error your getting ?

Comment: have you declared the xml of listview as @android:list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Mike. This is what I've done in my XML.

Comment: you shoud not use this kind of context : view.getContext()

Comment: read the doc for ListActivity. You'll know what @Mike means.

Comment: shouldn't it be **void**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this after super.onCreate

> GetListView();

Comment: Tried it but I get this error `Error:(24, 9) cannot find symbol method GetListView()`

Comment: doing this isnt going to do anything

Comment: my bad it's supposed to be ListView list = getListView();

Comment: OK, I've done that but the @Override error still remains (check the section above titled **@Override error**)

Comment: remove the onlistitemclick function. instead after initiating listview add this after setting the adapter

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
   public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          //Your Code, what happens when you click this item of the listview.
       return true;
         }
        });

Comment: OK, after that the word `boolean` underlines in red. Is that supposed to be boolean? Check latest screenshot above?

Comment: its supposed to be void. My apologies, as I copied that from my OnLongClick Listener code. Thanks for pointing it out, also remove the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

if you are extending ListActivity then there's a method which you must have to implement

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String list_item=l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,List1.class);
        i.putExtra("list_item", list_item);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

after getting string in list_item you can do whatever you want to do with it.

and if you are using extends activity.

```
ListView lv;
lv=(ListView)findviewbyid(R.id.listview);
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String list_item=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            }
        });
```

now its depend on you how you use that listview data.

Comment: Is `List1` supposed to be the id of my list view?

Comment: you didn't bind your xml listview to your code that's why it isn't showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see you have an error on your `@Override` which is probably saying there is no such method because your `onListItemClick` is not correct

see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long))

you need `ListView,View,int,long` as your arguments